# Swift: format console-log

Tags: swift, format, println

is there any possibility to create a custom log function?

This is how the default println("hello world") looks like:

```
2015-03-04 18:33:55.788 MyApp[12345:671253923] Hello World
```

I would like to output something like:

```
18:33 MyClass > myFunc [line 1] Hello World
```

Comment: You can check this librarys code https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the time, you can get the current hour and minute as String:

```
func printTime()->String{
        let date = NSDate()
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
        let hour = components.hour
        let minutes = components.minute

        return "\(hour):\(minutes)"
}
```

And for the function etc. you can use the Swift [Literal Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__`.

But you don't want to set it each time you want to log. So you could do something like that:

```
func prettyPrint(print: String, file:String = __FILE__, functionName: String = __FUNCTION__, line:Int = __LINE__) {
    println("\(printTime()) \(file) > \(functionName) [line \(line)] \(print)")

}
```

You call `prettyPrint` like that:

```
prettyPrint("hey")
```

And you will get the following output:

```
/Path/To/Your/File/MyClass.swift > hello [line 81] hey
```

But as you only want the name of your class, you can remove the path with the following function:

```
func getFile(path:String = __FILE__)->String{
    var parts =  path.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
    return parts[parts.count-1]
}
```

Or, as [ChikabuZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836420/chikabuz) mentioned in his answer you can directly check the class:

```
let className = NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder).pathExtension
```

**Final Function**

And here the final function(s):

```
func getFile(path:String = __FILE__)->String{
    var parts =  path.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
    return parts[parts.count-1]
}
func prettyPrint(print: String, functionName: String = __FUNCTION__, line:Int = __LINE__) {
    println("\(printTime()) \(getFile()) > \(functionName) [line \(line)] \(print)")

}

func printTime()->String{
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
    let hour = components.hour
    let minutes = components.minute

    return "\(hour):\(minutes)"
}
```

And the result will be:

```
MyClass.swift > hello [line 81] hey
```

You should also note @emaloney's answer to this question. Specifically that

> `println()`-based solutions result in output being captured by the Apple System Log (ASL).

Ideally switch to NSLog or a full blown logging system

Answer (score 1):

You should make an extension to NSObject, something like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject
{
    func myFunc()
    {
        myPrint("Hello World")
    }

}

extension NSObject
{
    func myPrint(text: String)
    {
        let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        let time = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

        let className = NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder).pathExtension
        let function = __FUNCTION__

        let line = "\(__LINE__)"

        let result = time + " " + className + " > " + function + " " + line + " " + text
        println(result)
    }
}

let myClass = MyClass()

myClass.myFunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, none of the `println()`-based solutions result in output being captured by the Apple System Log (ASL).

The ASL is the logging facility provided by the Mac OS and iOS that is used by `NSLog()` (and on a Mac is visible through the Console application). Because `NSLog()` uses ASL, log entries recorded by `NSLog()` will be visible through the device console. Messages logged through `println()` will not be captured in ASL, and as a result, provide no opportunity to go back to the console for diagnostic purposes after something has happened.

There are two big downsides to `NSLog()`, however: (1) you can't customize the output format, and (2) it does a lot of work on the calling thread and can therefore negatively impact performance.

[CleanroomLogger is a new Swift-based open-source API for logging](http://tech.gilt.com/post/118471923164/java-has-log4j-objective-c-has). If you're familiar with log4j or CocoaLumberjack, then you'll understand CleanroomLogger.

You can customize your own output format by providing your own `LogFormatter` implementation to ensure that your log messages are formatted exactly as you want.

For more information on CleanroomLogger, visit [the GitHub project page](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger).

Comment: Are you going to add color to the console log output?